# I edit the record then save it. Then i hit edit button again, da da old data in the form

Tags: php, mysql, server

I have 10 domain on my server, Only 3 of them affected by this weird problem.
Just upgraded my server to php 5.5.30 right after this start happening

I edit a record from database (MySQL) on the site, and save it (with changes). Then hit the edit button again to see the changes under that record, instead of new changes, old data is showing on the edit form?

What would be the problem or causing this error?

Thanks

Comment: cached page, probably. hit shift-f5 to force a reload.

Comment: I have tried every possible ways. Changed computers, changed browsers, still same.... It has been 5 days 3 domains are still doing same thing...

Comment: then start checking if the update actually occured. perhaps your code simply assuming nothing could ever fail, something DID fail, and now you're suffering the consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what my host finally come with and fixed the problem

So we have removed the "public" below and set it to "nocache":

```html
session.cache_limiter = public
session.cache_expire = 180
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `header("Pragma: no-cache");` to the top of the document.

Comment: Brian, I am a newbee, what document?
Thanks

Comment: The file you use to edit. If it works you'll need to find a global position for it.

Comment: No problem. I had a similar issue with my CMS.

Comment: I just confirmed that still happening... that code did not fix... I do not know what is going on...

Comment: My host just told me this: "This is to inform you that your server will not cache dynamic content in your server as mod_cache is not enabled and only if mod_cache is enabled server will cache the dynamic pages."